# ASP.Net Treeview AND HTML Table. Error : Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: asp.net, treeview, html-table, viewstate, httpexception

I am using a treeview in my webpage which is binding approx 2000 records at 4 parent node level:

```
A : bind child node count =1
B : bind child node count =25
C : bind child node count = 250
D : bind child node count = 1800
```

On click of these nodes there is a literal control on which I am rendering an HTML table from code behind.

```
The data displayed in html table for node A is 1 row 20 column.
The data displayed in html table for node B is 25 row 20 column.
The data displayed in html table for node C is 250 row 20 column.
The data displayed in html table for node D is 1800 row 20 column.
```

When I am rendering these tables on SelectedNodeChenaged event of the treeview. After 4 to 5 selection the page gives an error message. 
    Maximum request length exceeded.
    System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.

Now I know that the data I am dealing with is quite huge. And I guessed the problem might be with the huge view states.But I am not able to get to a solution. Please help with your suggestions.

Solution Tried are:

```
1. disabling view state for the treeview :-(
2. disabling view state for the HTML tables rendered on literal control. :-(
3. setting maxJsonLength="5000000" in web.config. :-(
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in webconfig

```
Browsers, and HTML in general, were never designed to handle large uploads
gracefully.
If you need to upload files larger than 4 MB, 
you can modify the web.config file manually to change the maximum request length


<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="5000000" />
</system.web>
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Specifies the limit for the input stream buffering threshold, in KB.
>   This limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks that are
>   caused, for example, by users posting large files to the server.

Comment: Hey,Thanks a Lot. Its working fine. May I request you to explain what was going wrong and how its being solved by this.

Comment: @MayankJoshi i updated answer. marks it as answer if u think this is helpful